# Latex label/ref for "fake" external figure

Tags: latex

some journals require each figure to be submitted in a separate document. However, they do want the figure legends to be listed in the main document.

I was thus hoping to do something along these lines:

```
\section{Figure Legends}
\begin{description} 
 \item[Figure \ref{fig:fireAntBiology}] \label{fig:fireAntBiology} bla bla ants
\end{description}
```

This would still permit to \ref the figure from the main text.
However, it doesn't work (The \ref returns the number of section "Figure Legends"). The following correctly gives a different number to each "figure":

```
\item[Figure \ref{fig:fireAntBiology}] \begin{figure} \caption{\label{fig:fireAntBiology}} \end{figure} bla bla ants
```

However, it also places empty figure floats throughout the document.

A solution should be straightforward. What am I missing? Any ideas?

Thanks!
yannick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmmm
one thing that sort of works is:

```
\section{Figure Legends}
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \caption{\label{fig:fireAntBiology} bla bla ants}
\end{figure}
```

But then I need to struggle with Latex's random float placement...

Comment: Have you tried the float package? Then you can use \begin{figure}[H] which is "stronger" than [h]. Check the table of placements here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the [endfloat package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/endfloat/) and split the resulting pdf in two separate documents for submission. Endfloat takes care of all the references and puts all the floats at the end of your document.

Comment: that's defendable... the problem is that the kind of journal that want tables & figures in separate documents will still want to have all the legends in the main text...

Comment: I've never heard of this case, but if you read section 4 of the endfloat manual, you should be able to redefine the [Figure X here]-marker to contain the caption of the figure. I've not tried that though...

Comment: maybe it's a biology thing (many journals don't even provide latex templates... %$(*&$#)
PNAS also wants separate figures: http://www.pnas.org/site/misc/iforc.shtml#digital

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to define the labels manually with the \newlabel command in the preamble of the document. For example:

```
\newlabel{fig:fireAntBiology}{{1}{}}
```

Would replace all \ref{fig:fireAntBiology} with 1. The obvious downside is that you now have to manually find the correct number for each figure, but it may work as a quick-and-dirty one-off solution.

Comment: note: hyperref redefines \newlabel, so folks using that package would instead pass five arguments not two:

   `\newlabel{fig:fireAntBiology}{{1}{}{}{}{}}`